# ObjectId doesn't find ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My database has the following data:

```
db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1"), "email" : "an_email", "color" : "", "username" : "", "__v" : 0 }
```

I query it with Mongoose using the following syntax:

```
User.findById("5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1", function(error, user) { }
```

which returns **null** for both error and user. Strangely enough Mongoose's debugging shows the following, correct query:

```
users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1") })
```

which directly queried on MongoDB finds the expected data:

```
db.users.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1") })
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1"),
    "email" : "an_email",
    "color" : "",
    "username" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Replacing findById with findOne and looking for email works. I really have no idea anymore... Any suggestions?

Comment: What about passing the `_id` as a query for `findOne()`? `User.findOne({_id: "5580c79aa11e7310b2985ab1"}, function(e, u) {})`

Comment: Tried all of that - As mentioned below I believe it's a bug of Mongoose 4.* in combination with the latest version of MongoDB (and Node 0.12?)

Comment: Weird, `findById` is working fine when I mimic what you're trying with Mongoose 4.0.5 on node 0.12.4.

Comment: Interesting - which version of MongoDB do you use? Would help me to precise the issue I gonna open on Github

Comment: Issue is raised - Seems I'm at least not the only one having the problem :) https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3079 Thanks for the help!

Comment: @florian I'm using MongoDB 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

findById() expects an id, not an object. Example:

```
Book.findById(req.user.id, function(err, book) {...}
```

findOne() expects an object so it works.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. req.user is a string containing the ID. I've corrected it above to make it clearer. I also tried instantiating an ObjectId manually and place it into findById with the same (null) result

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a bug with Mongoose 4.x - I reverted back to Mongoose 3.8 and everything works fine.